# Parse Emoji and create image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parsing, emoji

I can't find an up to date script (php or javascript) for converting utf-8 emoticons into images. As input I have a text string with new unicode smileys. Output should be a image in html. What is the best solution for this?

Edit: I tried https://rodrigopolo.github.io/jqueryemoji/
But new emojis are not supportet and the script mixes up utf-8 emojis in alt tags

Comment: same way you get images for any other letter(s) in Unicode: you find a font that supports them, then you write a text string using that font to some image context (of which there are too many for php/js to list)

Comment: I tried to use Apple Color Emoji tff font in css. But it did not work. Now I loaded all Apple Icons from unicode.org und extended the javascript from jqueryemoji. You can find it implemented in https://github.com/mmainstreet/jodel-web